# Using webhooks on dialogflow to Azure logic apps

Tags: webhooks, azure-logic-apps, dialogflow-es

Hi I want to use webhooks on Dialogflow to pass data to Azure logic apps(Http Request). I need your help since this isnt working well somehow.

Here is my settings.
[image]

Then, following message is returned.

```
"webhookStatus": {
    "code": 16,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 401 Unauthorized"
```

[image]

If I try same command on RestAPI Testing(Chrome Extention), it succeed.
What Shal I fix? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you including the SAS token (as described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/07/26/securing-your-azure-logic-apps-part-1-secure-access-to-the-trigger/) on the URL configured on the DialogFlow webhook? 
Have you checked whether DialogFlow is including an authorisation header as part of the request? 
The best way to compare both requests is sending the request to a request bin https://requestb.in/ and see what the differences are. This should help you to troubleshoot. 
HTH

Answer (score 2):

[image]
The problem is url Azure logicapp encoding.
You have to trasform url %2F to /
You have to do this change sp param

https://prod.zone.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/XXXXXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=**%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun**&sv=1.0&sig=XXXX_XXXXX

https://prod.zone.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/XXXXXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=/triggers/manual/run&sv=1.0&sig=XXXX_XXXXX

So You can use Azure Api Management. if you do not want to traform the url

Aldo Flores

@alduar

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow's fulfillment webhook requires that your endpoint be ["publicly accessible"](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#requirements).  If your webhook endpoint requires basic authentication or certian HTTP headers to be present you can configure them in Dialogflow's console where you enter your webhook URL:
[image]
If your endpoint has other access restrictions (IP filtering, etc.) you'll need to disable them for Dialogflow to be able to access your endpoint.

Source: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#requirements